# How to use StandardForm/DisplayForm with custom symbols

Tags: display, custom-notation

I want to be able to make custom notation similar to how `Complex[1,2]` is displayed as `1 + 2 i`. I tried the following

```
Unprotect[DisplayForm];
DisplayForm[Dual[a_, b_]] := a + b \[Epsilon]
Protect[DisplayForm];

Unprotect[StandardForm];
StandardForm[Dual[a_, b_]] := a + b \[Epsilon]
Protect[StandardForm];
```

But when I input `Dual[a,b]` it is left untouched. If I type `Dual[a,b]//StandardForm` it displays as desired but I want it to always display like that.

Comment: have you considered using [`Format`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Format.html)? would something like `Format[dual[a_,b_], StandardForm]:=a+b \[Epsilon]` do the trick? (I deliberately used lower-case for "dual", because I think it's considered good practice to restrict capitalised symbols to built-ins)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do this using [`MakeBoxes`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MakeBoxes):

```
Dual /: MakeBoxes[Dual[a_, b_], StandardForm] := TemplateBox[
    {
    Parenthesize[a, StandardForm, Plus],
    Parenthesize[b, StandardForm, Times]
    },
    "Dual",
    DisplayFunction->(RowBox[{#1, "+", RowBox[{#2, "ε"}]}]&)
]
```

Example:

```
Dual[a, y+1]
```

> a+(1+y)ε

Comment: This is perfect! Just what I wanted

Comment: I have on question though, how does Parenthesize work? I can't find any documentation on it.

Comment: You can examine `?Parenthesize` or look on this site.

Answer (score 0):

I think the canonical way (as described in [Defining Output Formats](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/TextualInputAndOutput.html#9464)) is

```
Format[Dual[a_, b_]] := a + b \[Epsilon]
```

[image]